# MongoDB Embedded Documents PATCH vs POST?

Tags: json, api, mongodb, http-method, embedded-documents

I would like to update an embedded document through an Api request and don't want to PUT the whole parent resource:

```
Parent {
  _id: 123,
  ...
  events: [
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

To update the embedded document, [RFC 6902 A.16](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A.16) suggests:

```
PATCH /parent-resource/123
[
  { "op": "add", "path": "/events/-", "value": {new event obj}}
]

Success Response: 204 no-content
```

I do like this quite a bit and will offer this.  But for slightly easier use, would an alias of:

```
POST /parent-resource/123/events
{new event object}

Success Response: 204 no-content
```

also be acceptable?  Also, what are some good resources regarding JSON Api standards?

Comment: does this have anything to do with mongodb?  You're talking about how to manipulate JSON, mongodb stores BSON and provides its own CRUD syntax, in particular, update operation which can $set or otherwise change various fields in the document.

Comment: More generally, building Api routes using a document database (mongodb in my case)... I do understand the DB CRUD and that is not my issue.  I am more curious about RESTful Api standards specifically related resources that contain embedded documents.

Comment: It's surprising there has been no further interest in this topic. The semantics of patching a document-oriented database over HTTP seems to me to be fundamental to modern software development.

Comment: @TomRussell There's been a lot of interest on this topic, but it's scattered all over the web.